# Disabling Zipcode field in zencart signup/checkout

Tags: php, zen-cart

Please help with this little zen-cart challenge.

Some fields especially the zip code is/are not required for the running of my online store as not all area where shipping covers has for example zip codes. The question is therefore how to disable those fields that are not necessary for signup/check in zen-cart. Can anyone help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the field not required, you have to do 2 things.

Go to includes/languages/YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME/english.php (or your specific language file) and remove the *

example, for Post Code:

In english.php, it says (around line 200):

```
define('ENTRY_POST_CODE', 'Post/Zip Code:');
define('ENTRY_POST_CODE_ERROR', 'Your Post/ZIP Code must contain a minimum of ' . ENTRY_POSTCODE_MIN_LENGTH . ' characters.');
define('ENTRY_POST_CODE_TEXT', '*');
```

and change it to:

```
define('ENTRY_POST_CODE', 'Post/Zip Code:');
define('ENTRY_POST_CODE_ERROR', 'Your Post/ZIP Code must contain a minimum of ' . ENTRY_POSTCODE_MIN_LENGTH . ' characters.');
define('ENTRY_POST_CODE_TEXT', ''); // *removed
```

then, go to your www.yourshop.com/YOURadmin and in configuration> minimum values clear out the number for Post/Zip Code.

to completely remove it from your page, you have to go to includes/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME/tpl_modules_create_account.php and remove the code block for this specific entry.
Something really similar to this:

```
<label class="inputLabel" for="postcode"><?php echo ENTRY_POST_CODE; ?></label>
<?php echo zen_draw_input_field('postcode', '', zen_set_field_length(TABLE_ADDRESS_BOOK, 'entry_postcode', '40') . ' id="postcode"') .
(zen_not_null(ENTRY_POST_CODE_TEXT) ? '<span class="alert">' . ENTRY_POST_CODE_TEXT . '</span>': ''); ?>
<br class="clearBoth" />
```

You can start reading something about customization for zencart on zencart wiki at http://www.zen-cart.com/wiki/index.php/Customisation_-_Templates

Hope this help.

Comment: @MasMacro,Sincerely,Thank you it worked. But again if you can help with this two issues I will appreciate. 1. What if i want to add a required field for marketing survey, say like: How did you hear about us, (a)Radio advert(b)social media etc. (2) Am having challenges with the currency thing. We accept Nigeria Naira only. I tried made it the default currency with value of 0.0063136 on the admin page since 1USD= 165.8naira.(exchange rate). The problem is therefore when I input item cost of 10,000 naira, it shows lesser value on product listing page but 10,000USD on Paypal gateway. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to make code changes to make Zip Code a non required field.  Go to Admin->Configuration->Minimum Values, and set PostCode to 0.